# Remove dropdown and add a textbox dynamically inside a <td> tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, textbox, drop-down-menu, dynamically-generated

I have a dropdown inside a `<td>` tag in a table row. I need to change it to a textbox or a textbox+button dynamically depending on some logic. Any help on how I can achieve this?

The whole table containing the `<td>`'s and `<tr>`'s along with the controls were generated dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give us a code example of what you're trying to do. This would be helpful in understanding where you are and allow us to help you further from there.

Comment: Can you modify the HTML or do you need jQuery?

Comment: Well, I will explain it a bit more. Each row has four <td> tags with each having a dropdown control inside it. There are multiple rows in the same fashion. Now for every row, the dropdown in the fourth <td> tag needs to be changed to a textbox or textbox+button depending on some logic with the dropdown in the first <td> tag. I hope I am able to make this question clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a `<div id="dynamic"></div>` tag inside the `<td>` and you could use something like:

```
document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML="";
```

and then:

```
document.getElementById("dynamic").innerHTML="<input type='text' />";
```

Comment: This one works for me perfectly!!! Thanks a lot! I used the <td> id in place of "dynamic" and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `replaceWith` jQuery method which replaces each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content.

Something like this will help you.

```
$('table td select').replaceWith('<input type="text" />');
```

Comment: This would probably work, but what if the OP wants it back again?  Probably be better to toggle?

Comment: @subt13 - That is not mentioned in the question otherwise I would have taken care of that. If you think that way there will be many "what if's?" from OP's point of view.

Comment: you are right, the OP's question is not worth answering, because it is really not clear what the OP wants.  Basically, all the answers are assuming what the OP wants.  I just thought it might improve your answer to add that.

Comment: This will replace all the select controls in the html page with textboxes, right? That is not my objective.

Comment: @user1209323 - If I knew your markup structure I would have used the right selectors as per your need. If you know which td select element needs to replace then use the right selector. I have shown you a way without even knowing your markup.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, in fact this is something I learnt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing since this is a `<table>` you have multiple `<td>`'s and you're asking how to change the html for that particular `<td>` with that dropdown box in it? There are many ways to [select that element in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) but I think you will have the most luck simply specifying an id for that `<td>`. Since you're creating this dynamically, unique id for that `<td>` is the easiest way to later refer to the element so you can reset the html in that element. If you have multiple `<td>` with dropdowns, you could even insert an id (e.g. 45 in the case below) so you can change just that `<td>`.

```
$('#tdwithdropdown_45').html('<input ...>');
```

Comment: You're right! I indeed did add an id for each <tr> tag because I felt I needed it and would come handy! I'll go ahead and add an id for each <td> tag as you instructed! That would make my job a lot easier!

Comment: Hold on, if you have an id for the tr, then just use that. Something like $("tr_45 td:nth-child(2)").html(... See: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector. Also, seems like you're kinda new, please participate in SO and vote up answers and accept if you like the answer.

Comment: So as per your first answer, I can use this : $('#tdwithdropdown_45').html('<input ...>'); 
Inside the .html(....) section I just add <input type="text"> etc and this should work, right? What if I wanted to add two controls like say a textbox and a button in the same <td>?

Comment: You can put as much html in there as you like.  $('#tdwithdropdown_45').html('<input type="text"><input type="button">');

Comment: I tried this, but doesn't seem to work. Here's the code that I am using : var temptxtbox = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"" + tempnum[0].toString() + ".txtbox\"";
                    var tempattrval = tempnum[0].toString();
                    tempattrval = tempattrval + ".4.tcol";
                    $(tempattrval).html(temptxtbox);